# jQuery Masonry not reloading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-masonry

For some reason the masonry plugin is failing to reload on one of my calls, here's the code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery(".pics-hidden").hide();

jQuery('#menu1').click(function() {
      jQuery('#thumb07').removeClass('.pics').addClass('.pics-hidden').removeClass('#thumb07').fadeOut(400);
      jQuery('#projectimages').masonry('reload');
       });

jQuery('.pics').click(function() {
      jQuery('#div'+jQuery(this).attr('rarget')).addClass('pics').removeClass('#div'+jQuery(this).attr('rarget')).delay(600).fadeIn(400);
      jQuery('#projectimages').masonry('reload');
       });

jQuery('.close').click(function() {
      jQuery('#div'+jQuery(this).attr('larget')).removeClass('pics').addClass('.pics-hidden').removeClass('#div'+jQuery(this).attr('larget')).fadeOut(200);
      jQuery('#projectimages').masonry('reload'); 
      return false;      
});
});
```

The bottom 2 calls work fine and reload masonry successfully, but the '#menu1' click function is failing to reload the masonry plugin, it might be something obvious but I can't seem to figure out what it is. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... .removeClass('#thumb07')...?

```
jQuery('#thumb07').removeClass('.pics').addClass('.pics-hidden').removeClass('#thumb07').fadeOut(400);
```

Comment: you are removing CLASS `#thumb07` from the `#thumb07` (id) selector. not sure if that's the cause of the problem but seems fishy...